# microsoft visuabasic powerpacks - how do I make sure they go with install?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a project that I am trying to install and run on another machine.  One of the dependencies is visualbasic powerpacks.  How do I ensure that the powerpacks .dll goes with the install?

On the properties tab I have set 'copylocal' to true, is there anything else?

Let me add a little bit more, when building the project, how can I make sure that all dependencies are satisfied and all required imports etc go with the project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ClickOnce, there is some information about packaging prerequisites at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%28v=VS.80%29.aspx.

If you are using Windows Installer, there is an equivalent at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx.

If you haven't decided on a deployment strategy yet, this page might help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33%28v=VS.80%29.aspx.